# Migrate content alone

Tags: nodes

We are using Drupal 8.5.X. As of today, we dump the complete DB to move from one environment to another. My concern is doing this, there are few sensitive information like user info or audit logs will be migrated to each environment. So I want to see whether we can migrate only contents and not the entire DB.

We use config_split for migrating the contents. We tried https://www.drupal.org/project/content_sync.. but looks like it is broken in the new Drupal. Any other modules or suggestions?

Comment: Move the entire database and then truncate those table(s) with logs?

Comment: @Kevin - we can potentially do that, but assume that i move a new release from staging to production. Do the above truncation, I would lose all my prod users.

Comment: From staging to production? That should only have to happen, at most, once (initial deployment). Configuration management and code should take care of all your changes being deployed.

Comment: Our application is not yet in production, assume that we have 200 contents to be migrated. So we add few items (say 30 items) in lower enviroment (say QA) and push the entire DB every week, to review with customers. So i would say instead of staging to prod, for now it is more of QA to staging.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [Workspace](https://www.drupal.org/project/workspace), which which was added to Drupal core (8.6.0) just a month ago. It's mainly about content moderation and let's you prepare content on one site that then can be published to another site.

So maybe, if you wanna stick to your setup of one live (master) site and multiple dev (slave) sites, then you could let Workspace push just the content from live to dev – if it works this way.

Unfortunately, I can't find any really good documentation about Workspace. And yes, it has been added to core as an *experimental module*. But I'd say, you should give it try and can maybe contribute your experiences back :)

Comment: thanks for sharing. yes, the documentation is almost nill :). Let me give a try and share my knowledge. Thanks.

Comment: One thing 1 noticed in Workspace module is, one environment needs access to upstream environment, as it pushes the content i.e Staging env should have access to Prod environment for pushing the contents. this might be helpful in some projects, but not in projects like mine where the environments are strictly controlled and not allowed to communicate inter-VPC.